# Kali linux having graphic drivers problems

Tags: kali-linux, display, freeze, hybrid-graphics, hang

I am using Kali linux .
My Computer machine has two graphics cards 
Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500
and 
Radeon HD 8670A/ R5 M330.

Intel 5500 is acting as VGA compatible Controller and AMD Radeon R5 M330 is switched off .

Problem is my Kali Linux hangs too much i think these problems is because of dual hybrid cards .

And I think solution is to disable the VGA compatible Controller Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 from the Kali Linux .

I need to fix the machine hang issue .

I would also be sharing /var/log/messages for showing you the errors to understand the situation .

```
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-kali4-amd64 root=/dev/sda2 ro quiet
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'standard' format.
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000057fff] usable
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000058000-0x0000000000058fff] reserved
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000059000-0x0000000000087fff] usable
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000088000-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000009b88dfff] usable
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000009b88e000-0x000000009ba8dfff] type 20
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000009ba8e000-0x000000009cc8dfff] reserved
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000009cc8e000-0x000000009cf8dfff] ACPI NVS
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000009cf8e000-0x000000009cffdfff] ACPI data
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000009cffe000-0x000000009cffefff] usable
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000feb00000-0x00000000feb03fff] reserved
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed10000-0x00000000fed19fff] reserved
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed1c000-0x00000000fed1ffff] reserved
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ffa00000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000015effffff] usable
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.40 by INSYDE Corp.
Jun  3 02:15:13 GOD kernel: [    0.000000] efi:  SMBIOS=0x9be80000  ESRT=0x9bf8c118  ACPI 2.0=0x9cffd014
```

This is the log from /var/log/messages/, 'GOD' is my username of the kali linux.

Comment: You say you see errors, but I can't see any errors in the log you've posted.

Comment: What are you even using Kali for if `dmesg` already looks like errors to you?

Comment: @Kusalananda xorg in Debian testing, is crashing in some dual card machines. I suspect this should be relative. Easier using other distro.